# COM object works in Win7 but not XP

Tags: c#, windows-7, com, windows-xp, com-interop

This is frustrating me to no end. I have a OPOS program that reads RFID cards. I wrote 2 C# COM libraries. Both work in Windows 7 with no problems. One of them was rather difficult to get working, but I finally got it. To get my COM libraries to work with the OPOS program I had to make sure that the target platform was x86.  Since I have win7 pro and I this same program runs on other computers that are x86 and run Win XP I fired up my virtual machine. I've tried a million things to try to get this to work and to no avail. Things I've tried

My one C# library (keyboard) at first required that not only I use regasm but also I had to have that library in the location as the Service object and the executable (ie my OPOS program) I found that in Win7 if i search for the GUID in registry there is a key called CodeBase that is basically the location of the library. If i put that same key into my XP machine I don't have to have the library in both locations. Tested it and it works great.

So then the need for another library came about. It is written in C# (same as keyboard) with almost the exact same settings. The ONLY difference between the two is the Network library class that inherits the interface has `ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ITapEvents)` AND uses Log4Net. I've never used Log4Net. But in order to get it to compile I had to get it, so I just copied all the libraries to my Program Files folder and compiled. I did not run a installer (don't even know if one exists) but like I said. it works in Win7.

I can't get it to work AT ALL in XP. The HResult that i get back is usually 0x80040154. Any clue what is going on? Anything that I should check?

**EDIT**
Showing instantiation of the COM object

```
BOOL hasit = FALSE;
try
{
    CString str1;
    CString str2;
    str1.Format("%llu", sid); //send as decimal
    str2.Format("%llX", uid);//send as hex

    _bstr_t uidStr(str2);
    _bstr_t sidStr(str1);
    INetworkPtr obj = NULL;
    HRESULT hRes = obj.CreateInstance(_uuidof(Network));
    hasit = SUCCEEDED(hRes);
    if (hasit)
    {
        CNetwork cti(obj);
        cti.SendStrings(sidStr, uidStr);
        cti.ReleaseDispatch();
    }
    else
    {
        LogWriter::WriteError(__FUNCTION__, "Error sending Strings", (int)hRes);
    }
}
catch(...)
{
    LogWriter::WriteError(__FUNCTION__, "Error sending Strings");
    hasit = FALSE;
}
return hasit;
```

Comment: You haven't really specified what exactly does not work, but `0x80040154` tells you that the class is not registered. Have you registered it?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic I've used regasm on it.

Comment: have you specifed `/tlb` and `/codebase` switches?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic well since you mentioned that the error message suggests it not being registered that should give you an idea of what I mean that it doesn't work. To desribe it in illustration its like buying a light switch and flipping it and wondering why my lights dont work when the same light switch (that is wired up) does work. They seem the same..but apparently they aren't. And I wish it was as obvious as it not being hooked up. But it's not and it's making me feel stupid.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic I did not. I registered the dll since that is what I did for the Keyboard library

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic sorry if that seemed condescending. I'm very frustrated at this because to me it feels like it should be a easy fix... So the illustration was mostly for me.

Comment: no hard feelings - 'I cant instatiate' would be much more succinct. Try registering with these switches and see if it works: `regasm my.dll /codebase /tlb`

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic no dice. I'm going to try and un-register it (and search through my registry to remove it completely, see if that helps)

Comment: did you get any error during registration? I use this procedure, and it works on all my libs on Win7 and WinXP.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic nope. `Types registered successfully
Assembly exported to 'C:\Dev\ServiceObjects\Network.tlb', and the type
 library was registered successfully`

Comment: If codebase in registry key of your CLSID is correct, then I would bet that the progID/CLSID you use for instatiating the object doesn't match the one in the dll. Where does you client import tlb from?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic this makes me wonder if something else is getting registered on my development machine, but not on my XP machine. But the output directory only has the Network.dll and Network.tlb.

Comment: if properly registered, your clsid's codebase value should point to full path of `Network.dll`. also, check whether the used ProgID is mapped to the CLSID in registry

Comment: Well.. I copy the GUID from the child class then go to my xp machine and search for that value in my HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID and it finds it. does that mean they match?

Comment: as for the full path it does show the correct path. file:///c:/dev/serviceobjects/network.dll

Comment: can you show the code which instantiates the object? Additionally, you say 'The HResult that i get back is *usually* 0x80040154'. What does usually mean, that you sometimes get a different error?

Comment: so I got a different error this time tried.. 0x80131534 I copied both the Network.dll and log4net.xml to the same path as the executable. The first time I ran it I got the 0x80040154, the second and third time i get the 0x80131534 error

Comment: This means that registration worked, but you now have problem elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723371/error-when-instantiating-net-com-interop-class-via-classic-asp  and also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception.aspx

Comment: you say you copied `log4net.xml`. did you mean ` log4net.dll`?

Comment: no, i meant log4net.xml normally Visual Studio copies a referenced library if i need it, and that library was not in the output directory. For giggles I copied log4net.dll to both locations and still no dice

Comment: not sure I got it. Why would you need .xml, it is needed only for docs. If your network.dll uses log4net then you also need log4net.dll, and other required assemblies. Maybe I just don't understand how your assemblies are laid out. Anyway, it seems that the instance can't be created for some other reason, build configuration, missing assemblies, target fwk... hard to tell from here

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic well thank you very much for your assistance. I'll keep poking it with a stick.

Comment: well, it's a slow day in the office :) good luck

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic So you were right it was a problem with the Network.dll. I took out logging and commented out a few things, and re-registerd it and it started working. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: glad to hear it works. :)