# Error in creating object by ProgID through VBScript

Tags: vbscript, com

Issue in accessing COM object which was registered in registry using RegAsm.exe \TSTestHarnessWCFClient.dll /codebase

Here is the VBScript Code:

```
Set oTestHarness = CreateObject("ProgramIDOfCOM")
If  oTestHarness.Init("EnvName", "UserName") = false then
    MsgBox("Test Harness cannot be initialized")

End If
```

Error Code: 80131534

Code inside constructor

```
public TestHarnessCOM_Class()
        {

            ChannelFactory<ITestHarnessExecutor> pipeFactory =
                   new ChannelFactory<ITestHarnessExecutor>(
                     new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                     new EndpointAddress(
                       "net.pipe://localhost/PipeTestHarness"));

            pipeTestHarness = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
            ((IContextChannel)pipeTestHarness).OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(2
                , 0, 0);

        }
```

Comment: There is discussion of this issue and some solution(s) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723371/error-when-instantiating-net-com-interop-class-via-classic-asp

Comment: Would have to see the object initialization code to help further. Common cause is not including a blank public constructor which causes the `COR_E_TYPEINITIALIZATION, a type failed to initialize` error.

Comment: The same application working fine on windows xp, but this one I am trying  on windows 7. Do I still need to add default constructor? Moreover, how can I detect if the dll has all its dependencies (primary/secondary)??

Comment: You must debug your code.  Project > Properties > Debug tab.  Select the "Start external program" radio button and select c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe.  Set the "Command line arguments" to the path of your .vbs file.  Debug > Exceptions > tick the Thrown checkboxes.

Comment: I am not a .Net expert but as per the given instruction I have done the changes but not getting any exception message in visual studio. Also If I am trying to register my dll using below command, 
regsvcs <Path to dll>\TSTestHarnessWCFClient.dll /i
getting TSTestHarnessWCFClient.dll was loaded but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found.